# how to install hypothesis Python package?

Tags: python, wing-ide, python-packaging

I'm using Wing IDE, how do I install hypothesis Python package to my computer?
I have already download the zip file, do I use command prompt to install it or there is an option in Wing IDE to do it?

Comment: by the way, im new to programming, so I not very familiar with working on cmd

Answer (score 1):

`pip install hypothesis`

Assuming you have pip.

If you want to install it from the downloaded package just open command prompt and  `cd` to the directory where you downloaded it and do

`python setup.py install`

Comment: so I key in: cd D:\App\hypothesis-python-master and then type in python setup.py install right?

Comment: when I key in, python setup.py install, i got this: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Do you have python installed on your computer, or do you ONLY have Wing?

Comment: This will help you. http://pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: I have python installed

Comment: Go through the link that I posted.

Comment: I got it working, reinstalled python, there's an option to add PATH, and then cmd can recognize pip, thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

As shakesbeer and hleggs wrote, and also by giving:

```
    easy_install hypothesis
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: key in this in cmd?